# Push item in array // Angular leaflet

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angular so I need some help on how can I push an item in the `markers.venues`.

My code is:

```
var app = angular.module("basicMapApp", ["leaflet-directive"]);
app.controller("CenterController",
    [ '$scope', function($scope) {
        angular.extend($scope, {
            defaults: {
                tileLayer: "https://dnv9my2eseobd.cloudfront.net/v3/foursquare.map-ikj05elx/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
                maxZoom: 14,
                minZoom: 3,
            },
             center: {
                lat: 52.38,
                lng: 4.8777,
                zoom: 6
            },
             markers: {
                venues: {
                    Madrid: {
                        lat: 52.38,
                        lng: 4.8777,
                        message: "This is Madrid. But you can drag me to another position",
                        focus: false,
                        draggable: true
                    },
                    Barcelona: {
                        lat: 52.38,
                        lng: 5.8777,
                        message: "This is Barcelona. You can't drag me",
                        focus: false,
                        draggable: false
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }]
);
```

How can I add a new item in the `markers.venues` in javascript?

e.g. I tried but didn't work:

```
 $scope.markers.venues.push({
    Amsterdam: {
                 lat: 52.38,
                 lng: 5.9777,
                 message: "This is Amsterdam. You can't drag me",
                 focus: false,
                 draggable: false
              }
     });
```

Angular leaflet is documented [here](http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-leaflet-directive/#!/)

Comment: `$scope.markers.venues` is not an array, so push won't work. Try: `$scope.markers.venues['Amsterdam'] = {/*...*/}`

Comment: @Yoshi Spot on, thanks for the structure notice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
   $scope..markers.venues['Amsterdam']={
             lat: 52.38,
             lng: 5.9777,
             message: "This is Amsterdam. You can't drag me",
             focus: false,
             draggable: false
          }
```

Comment: Thanks. With one `.` after `$scope`. :)